# Can Spring Integration Distributed Lock be Horizontally Scaled?

Tags: spring-integration, redisson, spring-integration-distributed-lock

I have a user-case where multiple services would need to interact with the same resources, and as such I'm exploring distributed lock libraries.

Since multiple services (>5) will be requesting/releasing locks, I'm building a central lock manager service to separate out the lock management responsibility.

I was exploring Spring integration - distributed locking framework, but the documentation is pretty limited. I wanted to get some clarity on whether this approach is horizontally scalable.

From my understanding, this framework manages an in-memory map of locks to enhance the getLock operation performance. Unless there is a pub-sub mechanism like Redisson here where threads are updated after a lock is released/expired, I do not think this approach would be horizontally scalable, as the in-memory maps across multiple instances of lock management service may not always be in-sync.

[Github - RedisLockRegistry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/main/spring-integration-redis/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/redis/util/RedisLockRegistry.java)

[Spring integration - distributed locks](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/distributed-locks.html)

Answer (score 1):

You question is not clear. If you talk about a cluster of your applications, then you indeed need to look into some solution for distributed locks based on some shared data store. And if you use such a store, then you cannot say that those locks are managed in-memory. Well, yes, there is a local `Lock` management, since we still need to ensure a proper concurrency in the current JVM.

According to the Redis Lock Registry docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/redis.html#redis-lock-registry, there is a `RedisLockType.PUB_SUB_LOCK` mode if you are interested exactly in pub-sub behavior.

Comment: "then you cannot say that those locks are managed in-memory" - so this is mentioned in the codebase (linked above), and an article I read online - https://medium.com/@egorponomarev/distributed-lock-with-redis-and-spring-boot-2c3f51a44c65
Sadly documentation doesn't give much details on this. I wanted to understand - if an in-memory map is maintained to store the locks, there should be a sync mechanism required to sync maps of multiple lock-management instances. I don't know if spring integration can do this synchronisation.

Comment: And if it can't do it this sync between maps of multiple instances, then it can only be vertically scaled.

Comment: The in-memory `Map<String, RedisLock> locks` in the `RedisLockRegistry` is just a local cache of lock instances. Every time you try to call its `lock` methods, we set the local `ReentrantLock` for concurrency consistence in the current JVM and then consult with the Redis. Always. So, in my opinion there is just no "in-memory" management for those locks.